# How do I define these table columns dynamically?

Tags: sql-server, xml-parsing

For a "simple" Request I get a Column filled with Xmls:

```
SELECT CONVERT(XML, event_data) As event_data_xml 
    FROM sys.fn_xe_file_target_read_file('Test*.xel', NULL, NULL, NULL)
```

The result:

[image: Sql Result]

one of these in details:

```
<event name="login" package="sqlserver" timestamp="2020-07-17T10:09:20.922Z">
  <data name="is_cached">
    <value>true</value>
  </data>
  <data name="is_recovered">
    <value>false</value>
  </data>
  <data name="is_dac">
    <value>false</value>
  </data>
  <data name="database_id">
    <value>1</value>
  </data>
  <data name="packet_size">
    <value>4096</value>
  </data>
  <data name="options">
    <value>2000002838f4010000000000</value>
  </data>
  <data name="options_text">
    <value />
  </data>
  <data name="database_name">
    <value />
  </data>
  <action name="attach_activity_id" package="package0">
    <value>093CAB81-B0B7-46CF-A807-F32D0469235A-2</value>
  </action>
</event>
```

My task is to generate a table out of these event-datas like:

[image]

I generated this with following statement:

```
Select  tbl.event_data_xml.value('(event/@name)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as event_name, 
        tbl.event_data_xml.value('(event/@package)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS package_name, 
        tbl.event_data_xml.value('(event/@timestamp)[1]', 'datetime') As timestamp,
        tbl.event_data_xml.value('(event/data[@name="is_cached"]/value)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') As is_cached, 
        tbl.event_data_xml.value('(event/data[@name="is_recovered"]/value)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') As is_recovered, 
        tbl.event_data_xml.value('(event/data[@name="is_dac"]/value)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') As is_dac, 
        tbl.event_data_xml.value('(event/data[@name="database_id"]/value)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') As database_id, 
        tbl.event_data_xml.value('(event/data[@name="packet_size"]/value)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') As packet_size, 
        tbl.event_data_xml.value('(event/data[@name="options"]/value)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') As options, 
        tbl.event_data_xml.value('(event/data[@name="options_text"]/value)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') As options_text, 
        tbl.event_data_xml.value('(event/data[@name="database_name"]/value)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') As database_name, 
        tbl.event_data_xml.value('(event/action[@name="attach_activity_id"]/value)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') As action_attach_activity_id
FROM
(
    SELECT CONVERT(XML, event_data) As event_data_xml 
    FROM sys.fn_xe_file_target_read_file(N'Test*.xel', NULL, NULL, NULL)
) As tbl
```

But the problem is, that I have to know each data's attributes' name, to extract this data. Because there will be hunderts of these kind of issues I would linke to generate these column dynamically. so:

Is there a possibility to generate column names out of xml-data dynamically?

Thank for help!

Comment: You can only create dynamic columns with dynamic SQL. A dataset needs to be well defined. If you don't know what columns you need, that seems like the *real* problem there.

Comment: Well... I "need" all... ;-) Unfortunately I understand the problem you are pointing to. I hoped for something like "foreach data in 'event/data' " or something like that...